# Can't figure out how to test proxy with Soundcloud API

Tags: proxy, soundcloud, python-requests

I am trying to use my proxy with the Soundcloud API. The format is

```
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=client_id,
                           client_secret=client_secret,
                           username=username,
                           password=password,
                           proxies=proxies)
```

However, when I pass something into the proxies variable like

```
proxies = {'http': 'notavalidip'}
```

the client is still able to log in and function normally. Why is this happening and how can I test that when I pass an actual valid proxy it will actually be used? I believe this API uses the Python requests library, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those options get handed down to [`make_request`](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/91b9231d6e1f165a4e634d27164ca32f45c4cfa4/soundcloud/request.py#L116) eventually being passed into `kwargs` inside the `request_func`, which is indeed backed by the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Your proxy is passing only because it has the wrong scheme. All connections to Soundcloud are made via https, and not http [by default](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/91b9231d6e1f165a4e634d27164ca32f45c4cfa4/soundcloud/client.py#L11). This means that you have no proxy setup, since your proxies dictionary has no `https` key.

See [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/9b41308b9f582dfa39db0ee57dc0b521a24538c2/requests/adapters.py#L255) how proxy is simply set to `None` because the dictionary didn't have the required scheme.

After modifying your `proxies` variable to `https` instead of `http` I got an exception thrown (`ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.')`, so no silent fails.

Hope this makes sense.